# How can I dump a filtered list of Makefile variables to a file?

Tags: filter, makefile

I'd like to dump all Makefile variables that start with `MYLIB_` and their values to a file called `config.h` as preprocessor definitions. This is what I have tried:

```
config:
    @echo "// AUTO-GENERATED - DO NOT EDIT!" > config.h
    $(foreach V, $(filter MYLIB_%, $(.VARIABLES)),
        $(shell echo "#define $(V) $($V)" >> config.h))
```

Unfortunately, `$(filter)` doesn't return any values, even though `$(.VARIABLES)` contains items that begin with `MYLIB_`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Related and has more answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117978/gnu-make-list-the-values-of-all-variables-or-macros-in-a-particular-run/59097246#59097246

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$(filter)` looks correct.
Possibly the cause may be the evaluation order between `@echo` command
and `$(foreach)`.
Does replacing `@echo` with `$(shell echo ...)` like the following
solve the problem?

```
config:
    $(shell echo "// AUTO-GENERATED - DO NOT EDIT!" > config.h) \
    $(foreach V, $(filter MYLIB_%, $(.VARIABLES)), \
        $(shell echo "#define $(V) $($V)" >> config.h))
```