# gnu make: list the values of all variables (or "macros") in a particular run

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

How can I list the current value of all variables (also called macros) in a Makefile when running make?

E.g. if this is in the Makefile:

```
CUR-DIR := $(shell /bin/pwd)
LOG-DIR := $(CUR-DIR)/make-logs
```

Then I would like it to tell me:

```
CUR-DIR = /home/johv/src/test
LOG-DIR = /home/johv/src/test/make-logs
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I ended up doing it like this:

```
gmake -pn | grep -A1 "^# makefile"| grep -v "^#\|^--" | sort | uniq > makevars.txt
```

which gives:

```
CUR-DIR := /home/johv/src/test
LOG-DIR := /home/johv/src/test/make-logs
MAKEFILE_LIST :=  Makefile
MAKEFLAGS = pn
SHELL = /bin/sh
VARS_OLD := [...]
```

`gmake -pn` is really verbose and looks kinda like this:

```
# environment
GNOME2_PATH = /usr/local:/opt/gnome:/usr:/usr/local:/opt/gnome:/usr
# automatic
@F = $(notdir $@)
# makefile
SHELL = /bin/sh
# default
RM = rm -f
```

Comment: Not all systems have `gmake`.

Comment: @FredrickGauss `gmake` is symlink on `make`. U can remove g and script will work)

Comment: thanks @AlexKhonko, you inferred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194957/what-is-the-difference-between-gmake-and-make) :)

Answer (score 54):

GNU make provides [.VARIABLES](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Special-Variables)
which holds all global variables' names.
However, this includes built-in variables(like `MAKEFLAGS`).
If you have to exclude built-in variables, some filtering like the following
might be needed.
The following makefile prints user-defined variables(`CUR-DIR`, `LOG-DIR`)
using `info`:

```Makefile
# Place this line at the top of your Makefile
VARS_OLD := $(.VARIABLES)

# Define your variables
CUR-DIR := $(shell pwd)
LOG-DIR := $(CUR-DIR)/make-logs

# Put this at the point where you want to see the variable values
$(foreach v,                                        \
      $(filter-out $(VARS_OLD) VARS_OLD,$(.VARIABLES)), \
      $(info $(v) = $($(v))))
```

Comment: How do I run it? Putting it in a `Makefile` and runnning "`make`" I just get "`make: *** No targets.  Stop.`"

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention, if your GNU make's version is 3.80 or lower,
this answer doesn't work.

Comment: Ah, yes I used 3.80. In 3.81 it worked. Also, I changed to CUR-DIR in the question.

Comment: how do you write it to a file rather than just print it?

Comment: @JasonS, have your shell handle it. `make > variables.txt`

Comment: This is great, a target which displays this can look like `vars:; $(foreach v, $(filter-out $(VARS_OLD) VARS_OLD,$(.VARIABLES)), $(info $(v) = $($(v)))) @#noop to prevent make: Nothing to be done for 'vars'.`

Comment: Thank you for this little bit of code! I just wanted to let you know that I'm stealing this to use for debugging my own makefiles. Do you want this linked in the code or???

Comment: @Jordan: Sure, you are free to use the code without attribution.

Comment: how do you assign the output of this to a variable?

Comment: @JasonS alternatively `$(foreach v, $(.VARIABLES), $(shell echo "$(v) = $($(v))" >> variables.txt))`

Comment: I like this solution, but it filters out any variables defined in the Makefile which are specified on the command line. E.g., if I have `FOO` defined in my Makefile, then `FOO=bar make target` will exclude `FOO`, because it's in `.VARIABLES`.

Answer (score 41):

Thanks to @Ise Wisteria, condensed down, this shows all variables, useful for large projects with multiple makefiles (Buildroot).

```
$(foreach v, $(.VARIABLES), $(info $(v) = $($(v))))
```

output: `BR2_GCC_TARGET_TUNE = "cortex-a8"` ...

If you get an error like: `insufficient number of arguments (1) to function 'addprefix'` this project had some broken variables... I trimmed the list of variables to show, only with a prefix `BR2_`

```
$(foreach v, $(filter BR2_%,$(.VARIABLES)), $(info $(v) = $($(v))))
```

Comment: MEGA THANKS ! It's exactly the answer I was deseparaly seeking :)

Answer (score 14):

It's also doable without saving all the `.VARIABLES` and filtering them out.

Moreover, if one of the original `.VARIABLES` was modified in your makefile, the two most voted answers won't catch it.

Check out [$(origin)](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/make/manual/html_node/Origin-Function.html#Origin-Function) function. This target filters out and prints all the variables that were defined in a makefile:

```
print_file_vars:
    $(foreach v, $(.VARIABLES), $(if $(filter file,$(origin $(v))), $(info $(v)=$($(v)))))
```

I get only a few excess variables this way: `CURDIR SHELL MAKEFILE_LIST .DEFAULT_GOAL MAKEFLAGS`.

One can replace `file` with `environment` or `command line` to print the respective kinds of variables.

Comment: Works great! Genius!

Comment: This works fantastic. This should literally be the accepted answer

Answer (score 6):

There are a lot of good answers here, but you're going to have problems using `$($(v))` if some of your variables are of the recursive [flavor](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Flavor-Function.html).  This is why you should use `$(value $(v))`.

This variation cleans this up a little bit, sorts variables by name and makes the output a bit more readable.

```
dump:
    $(foreach v, \
        $(shell echo "$(filter-out .VARIABLES,$(.VARIABLES))" | tr ' ' '\n' | sort), \
        $(info $(shell printf "%-20s" "$(v)")= $(value $(v))) \
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @kevinf for the great idea. I would suggest a minor change to prevent .VARIABLE itself from printing out in the variable list:

`$(foreach v, $(filter-out .VARIABLES,$(.VARIABLES)), $(info $(v) = $($(v))))`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @kevinf for the foreach solution -- if one wants to export this list as a somewhat machine-readable file, one will have a hard time with uneven quotes or newlines when using echo or printf, since Make isn't able to quote the data correctly -- one needs to use the $(file ...) function to write the data to avoid sh/bash complaining about invalid syntax. For example, use this in your rule -- it prints variable name, definition and expanded value:

```
$(file > $(MAKEFILE_ENV_FILE),)
$(foreach v, $(.VARIABLES), \
    $(file >> $(MAKEFILE_ENV_FILE),$(v)) \
    $(file >> $(MAKEFILE_ENV_FILE),    := $(value $(v))) \
    $(file >> $(MAKEFILE_ENV_FILE),    == $($(v))) \
    $(file >> $(MAKEFILE_ENV_FILE),) \
)
```

(This will still not allow to always distinguish malicious variables with double newlines from two variables, for this one now add a sufficiently unique separator infront of each Makefile-generated newline just after each comma inside `$(file >> NAME,TEXT)`)

Set MAKEFILE_ENV_FILE to some filename, e.g.:

```
MAKEFILE_ENV_FILE := $(abspath $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))).env
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution is an improvement of [Ise Wisterias Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7119460/4154514):

`./Makefile`:

```
ARG_VARS_0 := $(.VARIABLES)
#############################
# Documented Arguments START
#############################

EXAMPLE_ARG_0 :=
EXAMPLE_ARG_1 := ./some/path

#############################
# Documented Arguments END
#############################
ARG_VARS_1 := $(.VARIABLES)
# filter out any words starting with '%':
ARG_VARS_0_FIXED := $(filter-out \%%,$(ARG_VARS_0))
ARG_VARS_1_FIXED := $(filter-out \%%,$(ARG_VARS_1))
ARG_VARS := $(filter-out $(ARG_VARS_0_FIXED) ARG_VARS_0,$(ARG_VARS_1_FIXED))

.PHONY: list_vars print_vars # ...

list_vars:
    $(foreach v,$(ARG_VARS),$(info $(v)))

print_vars:
    $(foreach v,$(ARG_VARS),$(info $(v) = $($(v))))
```

List makefile arguments on the terminal:

```
$ make list_vars
> EXAMPLE_ARG_0
> EXAMPLE_ARG_1
```

print makefile arguments default values on the terminal:

```
$ make print_vars
> EXAMPLE_ARG_0 =
> EXAMPLE_ARG_1 = ./some/path
```

The funny part with the '%' is necessary since `.VARIABLES` sometimes contain  odd content, such as `%D %F *D *F +D +F ...`. The words starting with `%` can cause problems otherwise (e.g. some variables just not being printed).

Answer (score 0):

I like all the methods above, however some of them fail if you change values in the environment or on the command line. This one simply scans the file for any variables defined, then shows the current value. To prevent a variable from showing in the list, prefix it with `_`.

```
.PHONY: vars
vars: ## Show variables
    @exit 0 # Required to prevent make from exiting with non-zero code
    $(info Current variable values:)
    $(foreach v, \
        $(shell grep -E '^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z_-]* ?.?=.*' $(MAKEFILE_LIST) | sed -E 's|^([A-Za-z][A-Za-z_-]*).*$$|\1|g' | sort), \
        $(info $(shell printf '    %-24s= %s\n' '$(v)' '$($(v))')))
```

The one issue is that it **only** captures variable names starting in the first column, so it doesn't capture them if you do something like the following:

```
ifeq ...
    FOO = value1
else
    FOO = value2
endif
```

I'm sure there are other cases where it fails as well, but it suits my needs.