# How to change Netbeans 7 configuration specific makefile macros

Tags: c++, ubuntu, macros, makefile, netbeans-7

How to change C++ project configuration specific makefile macros in Netbeans 7 on Ubuntu 12.10? Where are no options in project properties opened in IDE.

```
CND_DISTDIR
CND_BUILDDIR
CND_CONF
CND_PLATFORM
```

Is there a specific project configuration naming convention for 32/64 bit configurations? e.g.  `Debug` for 32 bit and `Debug64` for 64 bit?

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this one too today. All I can find is that the files Makefile-Debug.mk, Makefile-Release.mk and Makefile-variables.mk are generated by Netbeans every time you save something.

You should make the changes in your project Makefile. What I ended up doing is turning things around and use the generated variables/macros. First place "include ./nbproject/Makefile-variables.mk" at the top of your own makefile. Then [see this other question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7119460) for a way to see all available macros. You can place that make command somewhere in your makefile, where you want to use the variables/macros. You can use make instead of gmake, and you don't have to put the output into a text file either.

Go with the flow, don't fight it.