I can't build my .o file with the makefile ("No rule to make target X, needed by Y")
I'm working on a C++ project structured as such:
/root
--/Client
----/build
----/include
----/src
--/Common
----/include
----/src
--/Server
----/build
----/include
----/src
--Makefile

Ideally, I want to compile and build both the server and the client from a single makefile.
The .o files would be generated in the /build folder while the executables would be in the /root
The makefile would have to compile the files from both the target and the /Common files
So I came up with this (sorry for the mess):
CC := g++
CFLAGS := -Wall -Wextra -I./Common/include -I./Server/include -I./Client/include
LDFLAGS := -lws2_32

CLIENT_SRC_DIR := ./Client/src
CLIENT_BUILD_DIR := ./Client/build
CLIENT_BIN_DIR := ./Client/bin
CLIENT_EXE := ./Client/bin/client.exe

SERVER_SRC_DIR := ./Server/src
SERVER_BUILD_DIR := ./Server/build
SERVER_BIN_DIR := ./Server/bin
SERVER_EXE := ./Server/bin/server.exe

COMMON_SRC_DIR := ./Common/src
COMMON_BUILD_DIR := ./Common/build

CLIENT_SRCS := $(wildcard $(CLIENT_SRC_DIR)/*.cpp)
CLIENT_OBJS := $(patsubst $(CLIENT_SRC_DIR)/%.cpp,$(CLIENT_BUILD_DIR)/%.o,$(CLIENT_SRCS))

SERVER_SRCS := $(wildcard $(SERVER_SRC_DIR)/*.cpp)
SERVER_OBJS := $(patsubst $(SERVER_SRC_DIR)/%.cpp,$(SERVER_BUILD_DIR)/%.o,$(SERVER_SRCS))

COMMON_SRCS := $(wildcard $(COMMON_SRC_DIR)/*.cpp)

.PHONY: all clean fclean dirs

all: client server

client: $(CLIENT_EXE)

server: $(SERVER_EXE)

$(CLIENT_EXE): $(CLIENT_OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $(CLIENT_OBJS) $(LDFLAGS);

$(SERVER_EXE): $(SERVER_OBJS) | $(SERVER_BIN_DIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $(SERVER_OBJS) $(LDFLAGS);

$(CLIENT_BUILD_DIR)/%.o: $(CLIENT_SRC_DIR)/%.cpp $(COMMON_SRC_DIR)/%.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@;

$(SERVER_BUILD_DIR)/%.o: $(SERVER_SRC_DIR)/%.cpp $(COMMON_SRC_DIR)/%.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@;

dirs:
    mkdir "$(CLIENT_BUILD_DIR)"; 
    mkdir "$(CLIENT_BIN_DIR)"; 
    mkdir "$(SERVER_BUILD_DIR)"; 
    mkdir "$(SERVER_BIN_DIR)";

clean:
    rm -r $(CLIENT_BUILD_DIR) $(SERVER_BUILD_DIR);

fclean: clean
    rm -r $(CLIENT_BIN_DIR) $(SERVER_BIN_DIR);

re: fclean all

Unfortunately, the message I get reads:
make: *** No rule to make target 'Client/build/main.o', needed by 'Client/bin/client.exe'.  Stop.
I know that this message appears when a file is missing, but since I use the % wildcard, wouldn't it work?
I've had a really hard time trying to figure this out, thank you to whoever would help me!

Use some diagnostics to see what make is trying to do - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5820303/how-do-i-force-make-gcc-to-show-me-the-commands

I would also structure it so that the client and server have separate makefiles, with a top-level makefile that invokes both

Please show the complete makefile.

Also see here for displaying the content of variables - https://stackoverflow.com/a/32768048/1607937

@G.M. I've edited the main post

The main problem appears to be the dependency $(CLIENT_BUILD_DIR)/%.o: $(CLIENT_SRC_DIR)/%.cpp $(COMMON_SRC_DIR)/%.cpp.  That states that e.g. Client/build/main.o depends on both Client/src/main.cpp and Common/src/main.cpp which is probably not what you want.  If you remove the $(COMMON_SRC_DIR)/%.cpp dependency that should get you a bit further but you're going to encounter other problems.

I beg to differ: Please don't show the whole Makefile, extract a [mcve] first.

Your rules are trying to do too much at once.
Look at the following rule:
$(CLIENT_BUILD_DIR)/%.o: $(CLIENT_SRC_DIR)/%.cpp $(COMMON_SRC_DIR)/%.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@;

We are trying to build $(CLIENT_BUILD_DIR)/main.o, so the % part is main.
Substitute that into the rule:
$(CLIENT_BUILD_DIR)/main.o: $(CLIENT_SRC_DIR)/main.cpp $(COMMON_SRC_DIR)/main.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@;

Oops: you depend on $(COMMON_SRC_DIR)/main.cpp which does not exist.
I suppose you wrote this rule with the intention of saying "the .cpp file can come from either directory". In that case you just have to write two rules, one for each possible source:
$(CLIENT_BUILD_DIR)/%.o: $(CLIENT_SRC_DIR)/%.cpp
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@;

$(CLIENT_BUILD_DIR)/%.o: $(COMMON_SRC_DIR)/%.cpp
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@;

$(SERVER_BUILD_DIR)/%.o: $(SERVER_SRC_DIR)/%.cpp
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@;

$(SERVER_BUILD_DIR)/%.o: $(COMMON_SRC_DIR)/%.cpp
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@;

As an aside: you should use $(CXX) and $(CXXFLAGS) when compiling C++ code and pass -c when compiling to object files.

I tried what you told, and now I have a different error message :
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: ./Client/build/main.o: in function WinMainCRTStartup': C:/M/B/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crtexe.c:151: multiple definition of WinMainCRTStartup'; C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib/crt2.o:C:/M/B/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crtexe.c:151: first defined here
... And about 30 messages of the same caliber.

Ah yes, I just focused on the major problem. You need to add -c when compiling to intermediate objects. see edit.

Thanks @Botje, I managed to fix most of my issues, however, the main.cpp files of /Client and /Server are finally built into .o files in their respective /build folders, but it does not compile the files in /Common into the Client's and Server's /build folders. Am I missing something ?

Neither $(CLIENT_EXE) nor $(SERVER_EXE) depends on any object derived from $(COMMON_SRCS) so this does not surprise me. You could do a similar patsubst thing to have the common files be compiled twice, or build a static library libCommon.a that you can depend on and link into the final executables.
